# Removing electron from inner shell of an atom

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Can we remove an electron from the inner shell of an atom without disturbing the outer orbital? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) How do you propose to take the electron out? What do you mean by disturbing the outer orbital? What are your ideas why there should be a disturbance? Please elaborate your question a bit.

Comment: X-ray fluorescence indicates that you can.

Comment: As @Jon says this is a work-a-day reality in the interaction of energetic radiation and matter, but these are stochastic processes and you can't pick a particular atom nor a particular time. Nor can you prevent the ionization of the atom from other orbitals as well (though by using a tuned x-ray source you can greatly increase the fraction of inner-shell events).

Comment: Nuclear internal conversion kicks out K, L, and M shell electrons every day.  What exactly do you mean by "without disturbing the outer orbital?" Eventually, that hole in the inner shell will be filled by an outer shell electron. There's no way to prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a photoelectric transition (usually with incident X-rays) can
eject an inner electron; [Ag X-ray absorption](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z47.html)
The highest-energy sharp edge is the onset of 1S electron ejection, and
at/near the edge, there is little leftover energy to be distributed in
disturbing other electrons (shake-up is a common term for such disturbance).[image]

This is experimental data from metallic silver, and the 'excess'
electron will join all the conduction electrons and achieve thermal
equilibrium.  Sometimes the energy spectrum of emitted electrons (Auger
electrons) is informative, and even just a few eV above the edge energy
(which is over 20,000 eV) that electron may leave the sample.

Once the electron is emitted, of course, the atom decays back to the ground
state by electron transitions.  The outer orbitals may be
undisturbed by the event, but they respond to an aftershock as that inner electron is replaced.